# How to make custom attached menubars?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, cells, undocumented, boxes

I would like to understand how to build an attached menubar. For example, `Image` has the following bar - an attached cell that arises when clicked on:

```
NotebookOpen@
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
   "SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/AttachedImage2D.nb"}]
```

[image]

Here's a minimal example that will show the bar:

```
RawBoxes @ GraphicsBox[
      TagBox[
         RasterBox@{{{0, 0, 255}}},
         BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte"]
      ], ImageSizeRaw -> {2, 2}]
```

So far as I can tell, the `TagBox` and `ImageSizeRaw` options are both necessary - removing either causes the AttachedImage2D to go away.

Such a tutorial would be need to explain three things:

1. How to build the GUI cell (something that looks like AttachedImage2D)?
2. How to access/alter the data of the boxed object to which it is attached?
3. How to associate the bar to a specific type of box and trigger it on clicks?

If a developer could help explain this, there are tons of fun applications here, e.g. making an AttachedGraph2D/3D cells, etc.

Comment: Search around for AttachedCell AttachCell.